# Getting access to class/interface properties from a companion object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit5, companion-object

I'm trying to make tests more flexible with providing interface with an abstract property for implementing in different classes.

The thing is that we can't get access to the property outside the `companion object`

Maybe any ideas how can I implement it another way?

I was trying some options like this :

```
interface InterfaceTest {
    val property: Property

    companion object {
        val necessaryData = getInformation(property.data)
    }

    @Test
    fun `dummy test`(){
    ...
    }
}

class FirstClassTest : InterfaceTest {
    override val property = Property(data = "true data")
}

class SecondClassTest : InterfaceTest {
    override val property = Property(data = "another data")
}
```

It can be an abstract class too:

```
abstract class AbstractTest {
    abstract val property: Property

    companion object {
        val necessaryData = getInformation(property.data)
    }

    @Test
    fun `dummy test`(){
    ...
    }
}

class FirstClassTest : AbstractTest() {
    override val property = Property(data = "true data")
}

class SecondClassTest : AbstractTest() {
    override val property = Property(data = "another data")
}
```

Comment: The code you’re posting as is doesn’t make sense. An `object` is a singleton, so it can’t access that property either without having a specific instance to access it on.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I can't get an instance of an abstract class or an interface, that's why I'm asking about any workarounds

Comment: But a workaround for what? It’s hard to understand what you’re trying to accomplish because the example code doesn’t make sense.

Comment: I want in child classes provide different data and run tests with this data. I understand, that my code example doesn't work, but I thought that it would be clear what I want to do

Comment: I’m still not sure what you’re describing, but maybe it’s that you want to test your interface? You can’t test an interface because it is only a description of what a class can do with no implementation. You can only test the implementing classes directly.